# Shrinking image and keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

The code I am using below destroys the aspect ratio. What can I do so that no matter the dimensions, the aspect ratio is always maintained?

```
<img height="25%" width="25%" src="{{ response.getPhoto() }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken right from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images). Fully responsive images that always maintain aspect ratio.

CSS

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:100px;">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wa5e6raa/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gngudgyw/) is working example (shrinking the image - but retaining aspect ratio):

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" />
</div>
```